# How to query and store data that must be calculated for several entries in a loop

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core / EF Core application (webshop) where I need to retrieve a customer's orders and display them in a grid (50 most recent orders).

The database-table with the orders contains basic information like ID, total amount, etc., but unfortunately it doesn't contain a boolean telling if the order has been paid or not, which i need to know.

Therefore, to determine if the order has been paid, I'm forced to get a sum of all payments that have been executed for the order and compare it to the order's total amount.

Which of approach would you recommend me to compute this information in an efficient and performance-friendly way that considers also a proper software-design? Adding an "IsPaid"-property to the orders table is not an option due to several legacy applications that are using the database.

So far I thought about following possibilities:

1. - Loop through the retrieved Orders
   - Execute a method that does the check for each order in the loop and returns a boolean (paid / not paid) for each order.
   - Possible disadvantage: The high amount of database roundtrips (we would need 1 query for each order)
2. - Add a property like "IsPaid" to my model-class
   - Get all Payments of all retrieved orders with 1 single database-roundtrip and store them into the memory
   - Loop through the Orders, determine if the Order has been paid and set this the IsPaid-property
   - Possible disadvantage: The property "IsPaid", which is used almost only for this orders overview, would be null (or have a meaningless value) for the rest of the application)

   3.

   - Create a sub-class of my model, class (e.g. "OrderSubClass") that contains a property "IsPaid"
   - As above, get all Payments of all retrieved orders with 1 single database-roundtrip
   - As above, loop through the Orders and set this property of the subclass
   - Possible disadvantage: I'm not sure if creating a subclass for 1 specific case like this is considered a good practice

   4.

   - create a Business-object that contains a property "IsPaid" and an Order
   - As above, get all Payments of all retrieved orders with 1 single database-roundtrip
   - As above, loop through the Orders and set this property of the subclass
   - Possible advantage: I could build also an Interface for this business object and use dependency injection
   - Possible disadvantage: I'm not sure if using a Model-Class as property of a business-object would be a good approach

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new table (i.e. payments) and set a foreign key referencing orders. That table could be used to store a bool IsPaid as well as any other information you might need to keep from the payment process, possibly making some other part of your work easier. Not sure if that is a viable option, depends on the legacy applications you need to support.

Comment: we already have a table for the payments which is related to the table with the orders. The payments inserted in this table are all paid at the point when the payment-record is created. So, unfortunately this is not helping.